# Ansible regex_replace templating error

Tags: ansible

I have a string I am struggling to parse in Ansible 2.0.2.  The string is of the form:

> "{u'tens_under_25': u'0', u'tens_over_hundred': u'5',
>   u'fifties_over_hundred': u'1', u'tens_over_25': u'0', u'hundreds':
>   u'1', u'fifties_under_hundred': u'0', u'thousands': u'1'}"

This string is the std_out of a utility that parses these values out of a number.  This string is captured with a register command into the variable 'response'. 'response' is a dictionary, with an element 'std_out' which contains the string of interest.

I am trying to extract the elements using the Ansible regex_replace filter, as in

```
  - set_fact:
      thousands: "{{response['stdout'] | regex_replace('.*thousands\': u\'(.*)\'.*', '\\1')}}"
```

This gives the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'\\' at 66
```

I can't for the life of me find a syntax error here, hope someone has better eyes than me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a dirty trick you can use here.  The output of your command is a Python object dump, and Ansible happens to have special code that recognizes that and unserializes it back into the appropriate data structure.  So if you do this:

```
- set_fact:
    response_dict: "{{ response.stdout }}"
```

...you will end up with a dictionary named `response_dict`.  You can then get the `thousands` value like this:

```
- debug:
    var: response_dict.thousands
```

Comment: That certainly handles my ultimate goal.  Thank you.  Still wondering why the regex-replace doesn't work, but this gets me to where I need to be.